# Error: Old-style type declaration REAL*16 not supported

Tags: fortran

I was given some legacy code to compile. Unfortunately I only have access to a f95 compiler and have 0 knowledge of Fortran. Some modules compiled but others I was getting this error:

`Error: Old-style type declaration REAL*16 not supported at (1)`

My plan is to at least try to fix this error and see what else happens. So here are my 2 questions.

1. How likely will it be that my code written for Fortran 75 is compatible in the Fortran 95 compiler? (In /usr/bin my compiler is f95 - so I assume it is Fortran 95)
2. How do I fix this error that I am getting? I tried googling it but cannot see to find a clear crisp answer.

Comment: you should find out exactly what that compiler is. (Quite likely `f95` is a symbolic link to something ).    The answer to 1 is its quite likely mostly compatible but will require some tweaking.  Is that really the only error?

Comment: You should show the code and the **complete** output and error message. The line of code reported in the error message at the very least, but more is likely to be necessary (see [mcve]).

Comment: Version 9.4.0 supports REAL*16 and COMPLEX*32 by default. 10.2 will not compile these even in legacy mode. I think that is broken, not improved. Its often old FORTRAN programs that you need to look at. Why break it for the older stuff

Comment: @user50619 That is nonsence. It just depends on whether you or the person thst compiled your GCC enabled the support for wuad math and bundled in the libquadmath library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are seeing is due to an old declaration style that was frequent before Fortran 90, but never became standard. Thus, the compiler does not accept the (formally incorrect) code.

In the olden days before Fortran 90, you had only two types of real numbers: `REAL` and `DOUBLE PRECISION`. These types were platform dependent, but most compilers *nowadays* map them to the [IEEE754 formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats) binary32 and binary64.

However, some machines offered different formats, often with extra precision. In order to make them accessible to Fortran code, the type `REAL*n` was invented, with `n` an integer literal from a set of compiler-dependent values. This syntax was never standard, so you cannot be sure of what it will mean to a given compiler without reading its documentation.

In the real world, most compilers that have not been asked to be strictly standards-compliant (with some option like `-std=f95`) will recognize at least `REAL*4` and `REAL*8`, mapping them to the binary32/64 formats mentioned before, but everything else is completely platform dependent. Your compiler **may** have a `REAL*10` type for the 80-bit arithmetic used by the x86 387 FPU, or a `REAL*16` type for some 128-bit floating point math. However, it is important to stress that since the syntax is not standard, the meaning of that type could change from compiler to compiler.

Finally, in Fortran 90 a way to refer to different *kinds* of real and integer types was made standard. The new syntax is `REAL(n)` or `REAL(kind=n)` and is supported by all standard-compliant compilers. However, The values of *n* are still compiler-dependent, but the standard provides three ways to obtain specific, repeatable results:

- The `SELECTED_REAL_KIND` function, which allows you to query the system for the value of n to specify if you want a real type with certain precision and range requirements. Usually, what you do is ask for it once and store the result in an `INTEGER, PARAMETER` variable that you use when declaring the real variables in question. For example, you would declare a type with at least 15 digits of precision (decimal) and exponent range of at least 100 like this:

  ```
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: rk = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15, 100)
  REAL(rk) :: v
  ```
- In Fortran 2003 and onwards, the `ISO_C_BINDING` module contains a series of constants that are meant to give you types guaranteed to be equivalent to the C types of the same compiler family (e.g. gcc for gfortran, icc for ifort, etc.). They are called `C_FLOAT`, `C_DOUBLE` and `C_LONG_DOUBLE`. Thus, you could declare a variable equivalent to a C `double` as `REAL(C_DOUBLE) :: d`.
- In Fortran 2008 and onwards, the `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` module contains a different series of constants `REAL32`, `REAL64` and `REAL128` that will give you a floating point type of the appropriate width - if some platform does not support one of those types, the constant will be a negative number. Thus, you can declare a 128-bit float as `REAL(real128) :: q`.

Comment: Well, I don't agree. We really should see what the OP does. The syntax REAL*8 and similar **IS** normally supported by itself, unless a specific standard is requested. This is the exact reason why I didn't answer this question although I know this stuff too. A lot of useful advice, yes. Solution to the specific problem? I don't think so.

Comment: @VladimirF well, I did add the caveat of "this syntax is usually supported unless you ask the compiler to be strictly standard compliant". The message says what it says: _old type declaration not supported_. So I told them how to write that in standard syntax. Whether or not the type that OP wants is supported at all cannot be known unless they tell us what compiler and platform they are using.

Comment: That's why such question should be closed, not guess-answered.

Comment: My gfortran does allow REAL*n even with `-std=f95 -pedantic -Wall` BTW. Highly unlikely the issue is in the syntax. There way too many legacy codes that use it.

Answer (score 2):

Javier has given an excellent answer to your immediate problem. However I'd just briefly like to address "How likely will it be that my code written for Fortran 77 is compatible in the Fortran 95 compiler?", with the obvious typo corrected.

Fortran, if the programmer adheres to the standard, is amazingly backward compatible. With very, very few exceptions standard conforming Fortran 77 is Fortran 2008 conforming. The problem is that it appears in your case the original programmer has not adhered to the international standard: real*8 and similar is not, and has never been part of any such standard and the problems you are seeing are precisely why such forms should never be, and should never have been used. That said if the original programmer only made this one mistake it may well be that the rest of the code will be OK, however without the detail it is impossible to tell

TL;DR: International standards are important, stick to them!

Comment: In fairness to the original programmer, `real*16` is quad precision and I don't think there was ever a standard for that. If you wanted quad you had no choice but to use some compiler specific syntax.

Comment: But there has been for 27 years for this to have been sorted since F90. However in  fairness to the original poster I have no idea why he/she has been down voted, totally unreasonable for a question from somebody obviously wanting to learn. Chrissakes guys, give these people a break, encouragement is the way to get them to see the light. Will up vote to correct, but this is why precisely why I think newsgroups were, when functioning properly, much superior to what we have here. And don't point me to meta, I deal with what I see.

Comment: If your compiler supports this much F08 syntax, REAL(REAL128) would be a standard compliant synonym for the REAL*16 extension.  Assuming that your compiler supports such a data type, REAL(SELECTED_REAL_KIND(25)) would also be synonymous (but would evaluate to REAL(-1) and be rejected if not supported).

Answer (score 1):

When we are at guessing instead of requesting proper code and full details I will venture to say that the other two answers are not correct.

The error message

```
Error: Old-style type declaration REAL*16 not supported at (1)
```

**DOES NOT** mean that the REAL*n syntax is not supported.

The error message is misleading. It actually means that the 16-byte reals are no supported. Had the OP requested the same real by the kind notation (in any of the many ways which return the gfortran's kind 16) the error message would be:

```
Error: Kind 16 not supported for type REAL at (1)
```

That can happen in some gfortran versions. Especially in MS Windows.

This explanation can be found with just a very quick google search for the error message: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56850#c1

It does not not complain that the old syntax is the problem, it just mentions it, because mentioning kinds might be confusing even more (especially for COMPLEX*32 which is kind 16).

---

The main message is: **We really should be closing these kinds of questions** and wait for proper details instead of guessing and upvoting the question where the OP can't even copy the full message the compiler has spit.

Comment: It was supported in gnu fortran though. Now they have removed it. I think a compiler warning would have been better than simply stopping its use. OR allow it with a command line option --sun_and_dec_compatibility

Comment: @user50619 Please read the answer again. It was not removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNU gfortran, try "real(kind=10)", which will give you 10 bytes (80-bits) extended precision.  I'm converting some older F77 code to run floating point math tests - it has a quad-precision ( the real*16 you mention) defined, but not used, as the other answers provided correctly point out (extended precision formats tend to be machine/compiler specific). The gfortran 5.2 I am using does not support real(kind=16), surprisingly.  But gfortran (available for 64-bit MacOS and 64-bit Linux machines), does have the "real(kind=10)" which will give you precision beyond the typical real*8 or "double precision" as it was called in some Fortran compilers.
Be careful if your old Fortran code is calling C programs and/or maybe making assumptions about how precision is handled and floating point numbers are represented.  You may have to get deep into exactly what is happening, and check the code carefully, to ensure things are working as expected, especially if fortran and C routines are calling each other.   Here is url for the GNU gfortran info on quad-precision:  https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/gfortran_quadmath/gfortran_quadmath.html 
Hope this helps.